# Effect of enabling zswap on zram without any disk swap

Tags: zram, zswap

I have set up a system that has 4 GB RAM with 1.5 GiB of zram. It also has zswap enabled. I don't have any swap partition on the secondary storage.

As I have noticed, the performance is good on my systems.

Is the zswap being used on zram? Can using zswap on zram lead to any performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/472227):

- `zswap` is a swap-specific, compressed, RAM-based "pre-cache".  `zswap` requires a separate swap device.
- `zram` is a compressed, RAM-based block device (that can be used for swap).

I recommend against using both together.  If you don't have disk-based swap, use only `zram`.

If you use both `zswap` and `zram`, I suspect the following will happen:

1. When a page is swapped out, the page will be sent to `zswap`.
2. `zswap` will compress the page.
3. If the page compresses well, `zswap` will store the page.
4. If the page compresses poorly, `zswap` will send the original (uncompressed) page to `zram`.
5. `zram` will compress the page.
6. `zram` will store the page.

In other words, some pages will be redundantly compressed twice.  This will result in wasted CPU cycles.

Since both `zswap` and `zram` store compressed pages in RAM, there is no advantage to using both.

Also, since `zram` is not a "pre-cache", using `zram` with other swap devices will be less performant than using `zswap` (at least in certain situations [as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/472227)).

Answer (score 2):

Zram and Zswap are two independent utilities.

Zram occupies part of memory with compressed pool(-s) which are used as in-memory swap devices. Zswap uses similar in-memory pool with compression but also can flush its content to swap file/partition.

So, you don't need Zswap since you have no swap. Just use Zram.

Comment: Could you add some info on the second question: "Can using zswap on zram lead to any performance issues?"? It does not seem to make sense to have a compressed memory buffer for a compressed memory swap, but the question is whether it even harms or whether zswap is smart enough to be noop if the swap space is a zram device. Otherwise, depending on kernel build options, one might even need to disable it actively via `zswap.enabled=0`, when aiming to use zram swap only.